# Xcode Version 11.4.1 (11E503a) hangs upon Source Control > Create Git Repositories

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11.4

My Xcode is keep hanging/freezes each time I'm trying to create repository for a new project. After clicking Source Control > Create Git Repositories > "**Create**", both buttons "**Cancel**" and "**Create**" become disable and I seems not be able to close the pop up window.

The only solution so far is to force close Xcode and re-open project. **Note**: upon doing that I can see repo being successfully created.

Wondering if anyone else is experiencing same issue?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Exactly the same problem with Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Anyone solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve it either. But I came with semi manual solution.

So, after Xcode hanging/freezing, just force Xcode app terminating

1. Open Terminal app, if terminal current directory is not your project directory, then navigate to project directory (command is like "cd Documents/Developer/YourProject")
2. In your project directory there must be .git directory, by default it's hidden, from Finder you can check is it there or not by pressing 'Command' + 'shift' + '.' keys (⌘ shift .) this keys combination will unhide .git folder
3. in the terminal use 3 git commands one by one:

```sh
    git init
      
    git add .
     
    git commit -m "first init"
```

And finally you can open Xcode and do other stuff related to git version control system. For example push it to GitHub.